# Play! framework project cannot build due to unresolved dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I was trying to build a play framework project using "activator".

I typed in `activator compile` at the root of the play project and I got the following errors.

```
unresolved dependency: org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.6: not found    
unresolved dependency: org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.10.6: not found      
unresolved dependency: org.scala-sbt#launcher-interface;1.0.0-M1: not found    
unresolved dependency: jline#jline;2.13: not found    
unresolved dependency: org.scala-sbt.ivy#ivy;2.3.0     
sbt-2cc8d2761242b072cedb0a04cb39435c4fa24f9a: not found    
unresolved dependency: org.scala-sbt#serialization_2.10;0.1.2: not found    
unresolved dependency: org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.10.6: not found    
Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries    
Error: Could not retrieve sbt 0.13.11
```

1. I have added this line to project/plugins.sbt file

   ```
   Resolvers += Resolver.url("binary-sbt-plugins",url("https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/sbt-plugin-releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
   ```
2. Also tried manually downloading the required files using these commands

   ```
   $ cd ~/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/
   $ mkdir -p scala-library && cd scala-library
   $ wget   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/peterklipfel/scala_koans/master/ivyrepo/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-library/ivy-2.10.2.xml
   $ wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/peterklipfel/scala_koans/master/ivyrepo/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-library/ivydata-2.10.2.properties
   $ mkdir -p jars && cd jars
   $ wget https://github.com/peterklipfel/scala_koans/raw/master/ivyrepo/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-library/jars/scala-library-2.10.2.jar
   ```
3. I also added the following to project/plugins.sbt and build file

   ```
   resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("releases")
   ```

None of these have been successful in resolving this issue. I should probably mention that the same project builds successfully on other machines.

Answer (score 0):

You mention that the same project builds successfully elsewhere, this suggests that the local Ivy repository needs rebuilding.

To rebuild `.ivy2`, rename `.ivy2` (in your home folder) to something else and then try running the compile task again.

I suggest using the `activator` installed in the project, instead of the global `activator`. To do this, run:

```
./activator compile
```

instead of:

```
activator compile
```